# Installing Sophos Anti-Virus

Tags: software-installation

Hi i'm new to Ubuntu and linux and need some help, im trying to install Sophos Anti-Virus and im running in to trouble. The guide reads,

Find Sophos Anti-Virus for Linux Free Edition and click Download. Follow the instructions to download the tarball to a temporary directory, for example /tmp.

Then Change to the temporary directory and untar the tarball:
tar -xzvf tarball

I have no idea how to do any of that, iv'e tried with no luck, would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: At the top of my head: download the sophos file, right click on the file, and select `extract here`. After that, open your terminal, and press `sudo sh ./sophos_file.sh`. Follow the setup wizard, and your done.

Comment: blade19899  i tried your suggestion, however i get this respond, Can't open ./sophos_file.sh.

Comment: I didn't know what it was called, after reading the documentation I found out it is called `install.sh`. I made an answer, that explains it more in depth.

Answer (score 3):

Before downloading the sophos install files, note that you need to accept the end user license agreement, and have an sophos account. so I am not able to provide a direct link. Start here to download sophos:

- [Sophos Anti-Virus for Linux](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-trials/shared-download-components/anti-virus-for-linux.aspx)

After download save it in your `Downloads` folder. Right click on the file, and select extract here. After that, open your terminal by pressing <kbd>CTR</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>, on your keyboard. type in `cd Downloads/sophos-av`. To start the installer, type in:

```
sudo sh ./install.sh
```

Follow the setup wizard, and your done.